# Retriving cell value from gridview rowcommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, commandparameter, rowcommand

hey I'm using to buttons in a gridview each which I want to assign to specific action involves retrieving certain cell values from the gridview columns 
I tried using

```
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow (((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

but it gives me Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

I also tried

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
```

it gives me the following error
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

note that when I tried to specify the commandParameters property of the ButtonField the compiler said that it's not a valid parameter for the ButtomField 
and I have 8 columns in the gridview so its not out of range

or alternatively could I use more than one select command button 
if so how to say which one is clicked??

please help me im desperate

ASP code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AcitivityId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="304px" Width="912px" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AcitivityId" HeaderText="AcitivityId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AcitivityId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ActiviityName" HeaderText="ActiviityName" SortExpression="ActiviityName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityLocation" HeaderText="ActivityLocation" SortExpression="ActivityLocation" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityStartDate" HeaderText="ActivityStartDate" SortExpression="ActivityStartDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDueDate" HeaderText="ActivityDueDate" SortExpression="ActivityDueDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDescription" HeaderText="ActivityDescription" SortExpression="ActivityDescription" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Avaliable" Text="Show avaliable buses" />
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Assigned" Text="Show assigned buses "/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Does this work: `GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;`?

Comment: nope it doesn't 
it gives me
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in a number of places on my site to get the row from an object triggering a GridViewRowCommand

```
protected void btnUpdate_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow g = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
    // other stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help @TrueDevelopment
but im still getting the same error 

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.